# Getting black screen when switching to an activity

Tags: java, android

As the title states I am getting a black screen when trying to switch to a new activity. The strange thing is I am able to switch to a different (almost identical activity) with no issues. (It is being run on an Emulator.)

My best assumption is either something in the new activity's `onCreate()` method (but the other activity's `onCreate` method is more or less the same and it works fine) or for some reason it is unsuccessfully trying to start the new activity over and over and running out of memory but I can't figure out what or why.

This is the code to switch to a new activity, the first nested if statement goes to the new activity with no problem and the second one gives the black screen:

```
menu.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            //check which menu item was pressed

            String group = (String)((PBMMenuItem)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition)).name;
            String child = (String)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            String addSession = getString(R.string.addsession);

            //set up intent
            Intent intent;

            if(group.equals(getString(R.string.cashgames))) {
                if(child.equals(getString(R.string.addsession)))
                {
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddCashGame.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (child.equals(getString(R.string.viewsessions)))
                {
                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewSessions.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
          //else if(group.equals(getString(R.string.tournaments)))
          //{
          //
          //}

            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is the class code for the activity that won't start properly:

```
public class ViewSessions extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.*/
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
/**Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.*/
private CharSequence mTitle;

private final Context C = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_sessions);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

public void openNavDrawer(View view)
{
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.getDrawerLayout().openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {

}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_sessions, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_sessions, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((ViewSessions) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

This is the XML for the activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.ViewSessions">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/pokertable_main"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/pokertable_menu"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/right_facing_arrow_icon"
            android:onClick="openNavDrawer"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

When I click to switch to the new activity and get the black screen my Logcat goes crazy printing messages like this:

> 07-15 21:07:27.092    1511-1522/pbm.com.pbm I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14484(873KB) AllocSpace objects, 61(1464KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 33MB/35MB, paused 1.617ms total 109.674ms
>
> 07-15 21:07:27.614    1511-1522/pbm.com.pbm W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.923ms
>
> 07-15 21:07:27.644    1511-1522/pbm.com.pbm I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8838(541KB) AllocSpace objects, 41(984KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 34MB/36MB, paused 11.304ms total 76.280ms
>
> 07-15 21:07:31.270    1511-1518/pbm.com.pbm W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.136ms
>
> 07-15 21:07:31.782    1511-1518/pbm.com.pbm W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 20.296ms

Answer (score 2):

Hello yitzih i think the wrong line is in your XML file where you are giving the wrong context in this line

```
tools:context="pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.AddCashGame">
```

> this should be

```
tools:context="pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.ViewSessions">`
```

Comment: good catch, i fixed it but the same issue is still occurring.

Comment: Have you tried to create your fragment first instead of calling its contractor direct ! like Fragment fragment = PlaceHolder.newInstance(position); and then replace container with your fragment.

Comment: You know what i think its a context issue ! are you sure from your context path ! i think it has an error  pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.ViewSessions